# Why the installable trigger is not working in my code?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been trying to run this code in Google Apps Script and make it update information from one spreadsheet to another one once the user edits a certain range of cells in the file, but for some reason the trigger is not working, i am using an installable trigger since simple triggers cannot access to other files. Here is the code:

```
function new_troop() {
  
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById("***");
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById("***");

  var source_sheet = source.getSheetByName("***");
  var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName("***");

  var seller = source_sheet.getRange("B14").getValue();
  var category = source_sheet.getRange("B5").getValue();
  var probability = source_sheet.getRange("B11").getValue();

  var outcome1 = target_sheet.getRange("B1").setValue(seller);
  var outcome2 = target_sheet.getRange("B2").setValue(category);
  var outcome3 = target_sheet.getRange("B3").setValue(probability);

  var source_sheet2 = target.getSheetByName("***");
  var target_sheet2 = source.getSheetByName("***");


  var range1 = source_sheet2.getRange(1, 5, 100, 1).getValues();
  var range2 = source_sheet2.getRange(1, 18, 100, 1).getValues();
  var range3 = source_sheet2.getRange(1, 14, 100, 1).getValues();
  var range4 = source_sheet2.getRange(1, 17, 100, 1).getValues();

  target_sheet2.getRange(1,1, 100,1).setValues(range1);
  target_sheet2.getRange(1,2, 100,1).setValues(range2);
  target_sheet2.getRange(1,3, 100,1).setValues(range3);
  target_sheet2.getRange(1,4, 100,1).setValues(range4);

  var distance = SpreadsheetApp.openById("***");
  var distance_sheet = distance.getSheetByName("***");
  var km = distance_sheet.getRange(1,2,100,5).getValues();

  source_sheet.getRange(1,7,100,5).setValues(km);

ScriptApp.newTrigger('new_troop')
  .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive())
  .onEdit()
  .create();
}
```

Comment: I am trying to run it in Google Apps Script, already edited the question

Comment: You should separate the trigger creation from the actual function because once you get it running you will be creating many, many triggers.

Comment: If you are going to create the trigger programmatically I would recommend that you check to insure that there is not already a function like it before creating.  Having too many triggers can be a difficult problem to resolve.

Comment: Do you know how to use the Array.map method.  If not you should consider spending some time learning it because your code could be greatly simplified.

Comment: Your current function will run on every edit of every cell in every sheet in the entire spreadsheet.  And it will also create an additional trigger every time in runs.  Is that really what you want?